# Video Screen Capture using python and OpenCv and video not opening

Tags: python, opencv, video, screenshot

## importing the required packages

```
`import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np`
```

## Specify resolution

```
`resolution = (1920, 1080)`
```

## Specify video codec

```
`codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")`
```

## Specify frames rate. We can choose any

## value and experiment with it

```
`fps = 60.0`
```

## Creating a VideoWriter object

```
`out = cv2.VideoWriter("Recording.avi", codec, fps, resolution)`
```

## Create an Empty window

```
`cv2.namedWindow("Live", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)`

# Resize this window
`cv2.resizeWindow("Live", 480, 270)`

`while True:
     # Take screenshot using PyAutoGUI
     img = pyautogui.screenshot()

     # Convert the screenshot to a numpy array
     frame = np.array(img)

     # Convert it from BGR(Blue, Green, Red) to
     # RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
     frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

     # Write it to the output file
    out.write(frame)

     # Optional: Display the recording screen
     cv2.imshow('Live', frame)

     # Stop recording when we press 'Esc'
     k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF # press 'Esc' to exit
     if k == 27:
        break

# Release the Video writer
out.release()

# Destroy all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

the video was successfully but in the end I could not open the video file "Recording.avi" or to be specific my video player won't play it
any help?

Comment: There is a chance that it's a player (or codec) issue. What player are you using and what OS?  You can also try: `codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")`. Use `cv2.waitKey(1)`.  Waiting 10msec is too much waiting for 60fps recording. 60fps is too much for screen recording regardless.

Comment: Thank you for your help I'm using media player also tried VLC on windows 10 also tried your suggestion and it's always the same the video won't play.

Comment: Do you quit by pressing ESC key?

Comment: yes i actually have the file everything worked quite alright but it won't open

Comment: You can try to narrow the problem - write NumPy arrays to the video file, without screen recording.

Answer (score 2):

So,

I reached this page as I ran into the exact same issue.
Default player error: An error occurred. Could not demultiplex stream.
I'm on Linux(Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) with screen resolution 1366 X 768

Steps followed to troubleshoot:

1. Since it seemed like a file type or codec error, I did some playing around with various codec names for fourcc: XVID, MJPG,etc. - Did not resolve.
2. Thought may be the computer did not have the codecs I was trying to use. So I installed the VLC player (globally accepted media player with most codecs pre-built into the application) - Same error in default player. No error in VLC, but also no video played.
3. Something I realized much later, in my code, I used screen resolution 1920X180, but my actual screen resolution was only 1366X768. Fixed it in my code. - Default player error changed: "MPEG-4 Video Decoder is required to play the file, but it is not installed." However, VLC player played the screen recording perfectly.

Solution: Based on all the inputs provided above, just update the resolution set to the correct screen resolution (or lower) and you should be good.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks !